# Do BoS Knights/Paladins/etc. stop dropping holotags?

Tags: fallout-3

Under what circumstances would Brotherhood of Steel Knights, Paladins, etc. stop dropping holotags? I got on their bad side by killing the ones outside GnR Studio, but they were dropping them. However, the three Knights inside didn't drop holotags.

Is that normal for those three, did I encounter a bug, or do they stop dropping holotags once you've gotten on their bad side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probaly encountered a bug, as every member of the [Brotherhood of Steel](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Brotherhood_of_Steel), just like soldiers of the US Army they are descended from, wears [a set of two Holotags](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Brotherhood_of_Steel_holotag) around their neck. They contain essential personal and medical information about the wearer and can be collected if the wearer is killed.

Comment: I'm tempted to agree, since everyone in the citadel dropped them.

Comment: @John, now how would you know a thing like that?

Comment: @Lord: I cleared the Citadel out of everyone but essentials. (And the no-namers who would eventually respawn if I played again for a while.) :)